# Using protobuf generated classes in an UWP app fails

Tags: c#, uwp, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have trouble using generated classes in my UWP app. The Xaml compile gives me an error message when I try to compile my solution:

> **Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999**: Cannot determine the item type of
> collection type
> 'Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField`1[System.String]' because
> it has more than one Add method or ICollection implementation. To
> make this collection type usable in XAML, add a public Add(object)
> method, implement System.Collections.IList or a single
> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.

My protobuf looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "MyNamespace";
package basics;

message TestClass{
    string TestProp       = 1;
    repeated string Names = 2;
}
```

I used these nugets to generate the class:

```
<PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.17.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.40.0"/>
```

To produce the error is quite easy. Just put an ObservableCollection or List of Type 'TestClass' into the code behind of a Page:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<TestClass> TestClasses { get; } = new List<TestClass>(); // <- this causes the error!

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My questions:

- Is there a way to get rid of this error or compile the protobuf file without getting RepeatedFields?
- What would be a good workflow to use protobuf and grpc in an UWP app? (Apparently mine isn`t)